# Single Linked list of .txt files in C

Tags: c, linked-list, txt

I have a question about a linked list. Is it possible to create a singly linked list from text files (the information content of each node of the list to be a text file)?

I am interested if I want, for example, that a singly linked list contains the names of text files, how, for example, when entering the name of a text file in the console, the contents of that file should be printed? Is this possible?

I have a big problem when understanding this kind of implementation. So I'm asking someone of you who has more experience with this kind of thing, if he's willing to help me?

I'm not looking for any implementation, can you just explain to me in words how it would work, because it's unclear to me. Also if there is any other idea to implement this, feel free to write.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards!

Comment: It doesn't matter where your data comes from for a linked list, you can store any kind of data in a linked list. Same goes for finding elements in a linked list. A filename is just a string, so implement it the same way you'd implement linked lists storing any other type of data

Comment: Is it better to create an array of such text files, then place that array as the content of the list?

Comment: That depends on your exact use-case and therefore is for you to decide

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do and what printing a text file has to do with a program using linked lists. Can't you just open the file with a text editor and print it from there? eg gedit myfile.txt